# Can everywhere discontinuous function map every non-empty open interval $I$ onto itself?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

It is written on Wikipedia:

> A strongly Darboux function is one for which the image of every (non-empty) open interval is the whole real line. Such functions exist and are Darboux but nowhere continuous.

An example of such a function is **Conway base 13 function**.

> So, I was thinking that maybe there are everywhere discontinuous functions that map every non-empty open interval onto itself?

I think that I am missing something simple here.

I thought on taking as a starting point the function $f(x)=x$. This one clearly sends every non-empty open interval onto itself. Now, I am not sure on how to "shuffle" values on every interval so to make it everywhere discontinuous.

If we define $f(x)$ to be equal to $x$ at all rational values then only the values at irrational points need to be shuffled, or, what may be even easier, we can define $f(x)$ to be equal to $x$ at all irrational values and shuffle its values at the rational points.

However, I am not sure how to do that, and more experienced users know better, so, how to do it (if possible)?

Comment: If $f$ has that property, then $f(x)=x$ for all $x.$ After all, $\{x\}$ is an interval. Perhaps you meant for every nonempty open interval?

Comment: @zhw. Yes, thank you. Surely I will do an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is such that $f(I)=I$ for every nonempty open interval $I.$ Let $x\in \mathbb R.$ Then $f((x-1,x+1))$ contains $x.$ But $f((x-1,x))$ and $f((x,x+1))$ are $(x-1,x)$ and $(x,x+1)$ respectively, hence don't contain $x.$ Therefore $f(x)=x$ is the only possibility. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $f(x)=x$ everywhere.

Comment: Nice answer, I gave both you and Gerry +1. Both answers are nice.

Comment: @Grešnik Maybe even simpler: if $f(x)\ne x$, then there is an interval $I$ which contains $x$ but not $f(x)$, so $f(I)\not\subseteq I$.

Answer (score 2):

For each $x$, $f$ maps the interval $(x-(1/n),x+(1/n))$ to itself for each $n=1,2,3,\dots$, so in particular $f(x)$ is in $(x-(1/n),x+(1/n))$ for all $n$, so $f(x)=x$.

Comment: This is a nested sequence of non-closed intervals that has as intersection one point. Continuity axiom is about nested sequences of closed intervals. What would be a necessary and sufficient condition on the sequence of nested non-closed intervals so that their intersection is one point? Is it a condition that that point is not an end-point of some interval?

Comment: If you have another question, you should post it as another question, not as a comment on an answer to a different question, @Grešnik.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it is better that I do not ask too many questions, I am here on the site only 12 days and already have 16 questions.

Comment: There is a limit to the number of questions a person can post in a given time interval. I don't know offhand what that limit is, but you can probably find it somewhere on this site. In any event, it's better that questions get asked as questions, and if you run up against the limit, well, them's the breaks. You might also try to search the site to see whether some of your questions already have answers onsite, as the place has been going for ten years now and pretty much anything anyone could ask at an intro level has been asked and answered already.

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Comment: I will accept an answer by user zhw. because he has less reputation points, but your  answer is more beautiful and less complicated.

Comment: "Fewer", not "less".